# Upload file to JFrog from Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am currently trying to upload a file to my artifactory (JFrog), I have the following code:

```
script{
def server = Artifactory.server 'jfrog1'
def uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
        {
            "pattern": "hola.txt",
            "target": "libs-release-local/"
        }
    ]
}"""
server.upload(uploadSpec)
```

}

However the file does not reach my artifactory and Jenkins does not give an error.

Help and Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can You find file `hola.txt` directly in workspace? If not try use `**/*`

```
server = Artifactory.server 'Artifactory'
def uploadSpec = """{
    "files": [
    {
    "pattern": "**/target/*.war",
    "target": "releases/${APP_REPO}/${version.trim()}/"
    }
    ]}"""
server.upload(uploadSpec)
```

Above example work correctly.

Comment: Hello 3sky, thank you very much, you helped me a lot, do you think I can talk to you by mail or linkedin? :)

Comment: Yep, use my nick and @protonmail.com

Comment: You can replace the ** with *. It works the same way.

Comment: @Eyal Ben Moshe, that's true, but `**` It's more readable for me :)